# Getting user Lat and Long from Dialogflow - FB Messenger Integration

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es

I'm building a chatbot that requires to capture the lat and long when a user sends his location on fb messenger.

I have created and Intent that executes in the "FACEBOOK_LOCATION" event. I found that this intent should give back something like this on the webhook response:

```
{
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "facebook",
    "payload": {
      "postback": {
        "data": {
          "lat": 14.556761479425,
          "long": 121.05444780425
        },
        "payload": "FACEBOOK_LOCATION"
      },
      "sender": {
        "id": "1588xxxxxxxxxxxx31"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/110)

However all i'm getting is this:

```
"originalDetectIntentRequest":{
    "source":"facebook",
    "payload":{
        "source":"facebook",
        "data":{
            "postback":{
                "payload":"FACEBOOK_LOCATION"
            },
        "sender":{
            "id":"32xxxxxxxxxxxxx73"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if I need to configure a parameter to capture the lat and long, or is this no longer possible in the DialogFlow - FB messenger integration?

Thanks!

Comment: Facebook has removed `FACEBOOK_LOCATION`, you can not currently use it in any new bots any more. They say they are working on a new way to provide Messenger apps with the users location, and in the meantime, they recommend to use the Geolocation API in a webview, if you absolutely need user location data.

Comment: @CBroe yeah that's what I thought so. I guess I'll use the webview option. Thanks for your answer!!